# iOS Reference Tab Bar Controller that is not root view controller

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am trying to reference a `Tab Bar Controller` that I have in my storyboard. The only problem is is that this `Tab Bar Controller` is not the root `View Controller`

Normally in the `AppDelegate` you would reference the `Tab Bar Controller` like this:
`self.tabBarController = self.window.rootViewController`

This won't work in my case.

The structure goes as follows
`Welcome Screen => Login Screen => Tab Bar Controller`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you make it root and present the other views modally? Or put everything in a nav controller and push+pop stuff? You don't want the welcome screen permanently in memory...

Comment: You can store a reference at your own property of the app delegate or any other object, rather than storing a globally accessible reference you can also pass it it to the objects that need it from the objects that already have it.

Comment: Should have mentioned that everything is embedded in the Nav Controller, and as I am typing this I am realizing that I can probably reference it through the Nav Controller?

Comment: If the nav controller is the root then it should have an array of childViewControllers.  Loop through the array looking for the UITabBarController.